# Copy a row based on value in a cell, split the values in that cell and paste the row n number of times with split value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a row when there is a pipe character | in a particular column, count the number of characters |, insert those many rows and paste the copied cell but change the value in that column. Only one value instead of multiple values separated by |.

[image]

Column C2 may not have multiple values separated by |.
When there are multiple values, split those values and insert as new row.

Output should look like
[image]

I am stuck on pasting the row n times

```vb
Private Sub copyRows()

Dim c As Range
Dim count As Integer, rownum As Integer

For Each c In Range("I:I")
    If c.Value Like "*|*" Then
        count = Len(c) - Len(Replace(c, "|", ""))
        rownum = ActiveCell.row
        Rows(rownum).Select
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Transform Data: Split Column Cells To Rows

[image]
[image]

```vb
Sub SplitColumnToRows()
    
    Const WS_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const DEL_COLUMN As Long = 9 ' I
    Const DELIMITER As String = "|"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containig this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(DEL_COLUMN)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sArr() As String, cell As Range, r As Long, s As Long, sUpper As Long
    
    For r = crg.Rows.Count To FIRST_ROW Step -1
        Set cell = crg.Cells(r)
        sArr = Split(CStr(cell.Value), DELIMITER)
        sUpper = UBound(sArr)
        If sUpper > 0 Then
            With rg.Rows(r)
                .Copy
                .Offset(1).Resize(sUpper) _
                    .Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End With
            For s = 0 To sUpper
                cell.Offset(s).Value = sArr(s)
            Next s
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Column split to rows.", vbInformation

End Sub
```